# Add fuzziness to a field in elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

I just want to support fuzzy queries for some fields, how can i do this?I have tried n-gram tokenizer but it didn't give proper result when I used **match_phrase**.

Comment: Can you please put your index mapping, sample document, what you have tried and what issue you are getting. This details will help community to answer in better way.

Comment: I hope you have go through [Fuzzy Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html) documentation of the elasticsearch.